# IE7 Overlapping Text

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, word-wrap

I'm having issues with a client website in which the text for the three columns on the homepage is overlapping and causing the entire homepage to break.

I've added the following CSS styles to the `body` tag hoping this would fix it, however it did not:

```
  word-wrap: break-word; /* Current Browsers */
  -ms-word-wrap: break-word; /* IE8 */
  white-space: normal; /* IE7 Hack */
```

Attached are two images displaying the error in IE7, and what it should look like

[image: IE7 Error]

[image: Correct formatting]

What can I do to ensure this isn't happening in IE7? It works fine in versions of IE8 +

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using `diaplsy:inline-block;` on some block elemnts (like `div`) to achive your layout. I'm pretty sure that's the cause of your problem (not `word-wrap`) because IE7 dont recognize `inline-block`.

here is a IE7 hack for inline-block taken from [here](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/)

```
some-selector
{
    display: inline-block; /*for browser who support it*/
    *display: inline;      /*hack for IE7*/
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Actually no, It's using `float: left;` to have them positioned. I didn't build this site, I've taken it over from a previous developer.

Comment: in order to help you further, you will need to post your code. create a JsFiddle with the relevant markup and CSS.